# RequireJS errors in PhantomJS but not Chrome/FireFox

Tags: javascript, requirejs, phantomjs

I have two files in the same directory:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["fakeTest"], function () {});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    alert('foo');
});
```

If I run this in Chrome/FireFox I get what I expect. If I try and run from CMD with this:

```
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 testFile.html
```

I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'fakeTest'
>
> phantomjs://bootstrap.js:299 in require
>   phantomjs://bootstrap.js:263 in require

I've tried with the newest PhantomJS and older versions, same with RequireJS. I've looked all over Google and haven't been able to find any solution. I've had someone else try this on their computer and they've seen the same problems. I've simplified the files as much as I could and am unsure what else to try at this point.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running PhantomJS directly, then you need to create a script to load the page.  See the example below. That said, if you are trying to test your Web pages, there are [headless testing frameworks](http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html) designed to work with PhantomJS.  These frameworks take care of the details of loading HTML, scripts, and other resources when running tests.  Personally, I use the [Karma Test Runner](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) with the [karma-requirejs plugin](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-requirejs) to run unit tests.

If you are trying to run PhatomJS directly, you need to create a script to open the HTML page.  In the simple example below, run.js, the 'testFile.html' page is opened, and it prints the title of the page.  It then sets a 100ms time out that prints the title again and exits.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('testFile.html', function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title;
  });
  console.log('Page title is ' + title);
  setTimeout(function () {
    var title  = page.evaluate(function () {
      return document.title;
    });
    console.log('Page title is ' + title);
    phantom.exit()
  }, 100);
});
```

Below is an example of the output running the command:

```
phantomjs run.js 
Page title is Original Title
Page title is Title Updated
```

The reason for the timeout is that the AMD modules are loaded asynchronously, and you'll need to build a way in your run.js script to take into account the asynchronous nature of the AMD modules. I strongly suggest using one of the existing test runners that integrate with RequireJS instead of reinventing the wheel.

To see this in action, modify your testFile.html to be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Original Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.20/require.js">    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["fakeTest"], function () {});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And the fakeTest.js to be:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
  document.title = 'Title Updated';
});
```